# Create a Map from an array of objects with a condition on array elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, typescript

I have an array of objects which i receive from a db:

```js
[{
    key: 'PRODUCT',
    item_key: 'ITEM_01',
    sequence: 1
  },
  {
    key: 'STORE',
    item_key: 'STORE_01',
    sequence: 2
  }
]
```

I want to create a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) from it but the condition is, i want the `item_key` to be the map key, and only the corresponding array element which matches the `item_key` will be the value of that map key. So the map looks like

```js
{
  'ITEM_01' => [{
    key: 'PRODUCT',
    item_key: 'ITEM_01',
    sequence: 1
  }],
  'STORE_01' => [{
    key: 'STORE',
    item_key: 'STORE_01',
    sequence: 2
  }]
}
```

I've kept the value of map keys as an array because there can be more values matching the map key in future. How can i do this?

P.S. by `Map` i don't mean the array function `map`, but the JS/TS [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: `there can be more values matching the map key in future`  It might be a good idea to update your example showing this.  As this is pretty much fundamental to the question, as your will likely want `reduce` not `map`..

Comment: @Keith I meant the JS/TS Map object, not the array function. Added it in the edit.

Comment: That's not what I'm talking about, your wanting the Value to be an array, because the source could have multiple keys with the same key, so your result is will want reducing `reduce`,.  Your example data does not show a duplicate, so I was pointing out it would be a good idea to show it, as it's a pretty fundamental aspect of your output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create an object, if the key exists in the object then push to the array, otherwise create an array and push the item:

```js
const items = [{
    key: 'PRODUCT',
    item_key: 'ITEM_01',
    sequence: 1
  },
  {
    key: 'STORE',
    item_key: 'STORE_01',
    sequence: 2
  }
]

const result = items.reduce((obj, item) => {
  if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(item.item_key)) {
    obj[item.item_key] = [];
  }
  
  obj[item.item_key].push(item);

  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Here is an exmaple with Map:

```js
const map = new Map();

const items = [{
    key: 'PRODUCT',
    item_key: 'ITEM_01',
    sequence: 1
  },
  {
    key: 'STORE',
    item_key: 'STORE_01',
    sequence: 2
  }
]

items.forEach(item => {
  if (map.has(item.item_key)) {
    map.get(item.item_key).push(item);
  } else {
    map.set(item.item_key, [item])
  }
});

console.log(Object.fromEntries(map))
```

Comment: This works, but i want to set it in a Map, the global object. I didn't mean to use the array function `map` as i've added it in an update to the question, i wanted the result inside a Map.

Comment: @Matt_crud I have added an example with map, using forEach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Map` constructor

```js
const arr = [{
    key: 'PRODUCT',
    item_key: 'ITEM_01',
    sequence: 1
  },
  {
    key: 'STORE',
    item_key: 'STORE_01',
    sequence: 2
  }
];

const myMap = new Map();
arr.forEach(obj => myMap.set(obj.item_key, obj));

console.log(Object.fromEntries(myMap));
```

Comment: can you edit this to use `Map`'s set function? I have to initialize an empty Map as a global variable and set it accordingly at runtime.

Comment: Updated, is this what you wanted?

Comment: @Matt_crud  This does not handle duplicate, the reason for value been an array, or was that part not important after all?.

Comment: @Keith that wasn't important.

Answer (score 1):

```js
    /**
     * return the value of map keys as an array
     * @param list data from DB
     * @param map new map or any map you already have
     */
    function saveToMap(list: any[], map: Map<string, any[]>) {
        list.forEach(obj => {
            if (map.has(obj.key)) {
                map.get(obj.key)?.push(obj)
            } else {
                map.set(obj.key, [obj])
            }
        })
        return [...map.keys()]
    }
    
    const list = [
        {
            key: "PRODUCT",
            item_key: "ITEM_01",
            sequence: 1,
        },
        {
            key: "STORE",
            item_key: "STORE_01",
            sequence: 2,
        },
    ]
    // new map or any map you already have
    const map = new Map()
    const res = saveToMap(list, map)
    console.log(res)
```

Comment: Can someone tell me why my answer doesn't have a "Run code sinppet" button ?

Answer (score 0):

You reduce it.

```js
let arr =[{
    key: 'PRODUCT',
    item_key: 'ITEM_01',
    sequence: 1
  },
  {
    key: 'STORE',
    item_key: 'STORE_01',
    sequence: 2
  }
]

let result = arr.reduce((prev, curr) => {
   prev[curr.item_key] = curr
   return prev;
}, {})

console.log(result);
```